# key command > look up highlighted word?

Tags: dictionary, highlights, look-up

Is there a keycommand for looking up a highlighted word on macos? Without the mouse, no hovering.
I am using vimium when browsing the web and would like to be able to look up highlighted words without ever having to touch the mouse.

(macOS Mojave)

Thanks,
// H

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a default - you can double check in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services…

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  will 'Look Up in Dictionary'

[image]

Comment: hmmm, this is not working on my computer. Does this work for you?

Comment: It does indeed.

Comment: On my machine (macOS Catalina) there is no keyboard shortcut assigned by default for "Look Up In Dictionary". But I can assign a key combo like you did, and that works.

Comment: @Nic - I wasn't certain whether or not it was default - I've been messing with stuff for too many years to remember ;) Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: are you guys hovering the mouse over the word or can you do it by only having the word highlighted?

Comment: No, you have to hover. There's no way to do exactly what the OP requested.